# create RDS user with boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I'm trying to create an AWS Lambda webservice that takes a payload with a new username / password to create a new database and user in an RDS instance.

I'd like to use Boto3 to accomplish this, but I can't seem to find any documentation for this function.

Is this possible using this setup?

Comment: New users in RDS instance means, a user in the database system or a user in a db table?

Comment: @ashan-- a new database user, with privs on a new DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently AWS SDKs for RDS(Including [Boto3 SDK](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/rds.html)) does not support this nor the AWS CLI.

Its because, creating DB users unique to each DB instance type (mysql, oracle & etc).

The option you have is to run a DDL query using your respective database driver.

Comment: Thanks-- can you give a quick example of how to execute arbitrary sql via boto, or is this also not supported? It seems like there must be a way to accomplish what I'm hoping to do using lambda.

Comment: You should be able to perform it using your python driver for database access, executing a db query

Answer (score 0):

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.generate_db_auth_token documents how create an auth token for connecting to an RDS instance and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html covers other setup details.